# Deep query is came string when GET param json multidimensional on Axios / Vue / Node

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

When I am tryin to send Get request api with nested query i have a some problem on api side.
Vue query dimension while bigger than 2 that query became string on the Api side I want to take an object but API recieve string after 2 dimension. Let me show you code,

```
Query: {
       firstQuery: {
         insideOne: {
           abc: 'cde'
         }
       },
       secondQuery: {
         insideTwo: {
           cde: 'efg'
         }
       }
```

---

When i console log on node js

```
req.query.firstQuery.insideOne.abc //undefined
firstQuery  //firstQuery: '{"insideOne":{"abc":"cde"}}'
```

Why that become like that? How can i handle it? (exclude json parse)

Comment: Are you using body-parser?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Yes I am, also I am sending request on req.query.